# Preverification error in j2me application of eclipse

Tags: java-me

Installed lwuit jar and when i am running j2me application getting error when am setting build path then error arises in eclipse.

Error preverification Error

Comment: I got the same when I integrated lwuit with netbeans. Solution: I removed and added the lib again, restarted my ide and the error was gone. Hope it works for you.